# What is the difference between "TextEditingController titleController;" and "titleController = TextEditingController();"?

Tags: flutter, dart, instantiation

Sorry if this is a really simple question but still is a fundamental question for me to know what is the difference between these two line of code?:

```
TextEditingController titleController;
```

and

```
titleController = TextEditingController();
```

For more clearance I mean what would be the difference between `titleController` in the first line of the code versus the second line?

When we should use the first and when the second?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both lines must be used together. Let's see what each line represents:

The "first line":

```
TextEditingController titleController;
```

Is only declaring a variable of the `TextEditingController` type, called `titleController`. It has not been given a value yet, and while it doesn't receive one its value will be considered `null`.

There are other ways to declare a variable, (like declaring as `dynamic`, or using `var`, `final`, `const`, etc) and you can read more of that in the [Dart's Language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#variables). I won't explain them here since it is not so much related to the question.

The "second line":

```
titleController = TextEditingController();
```

Is giving a value to the `titleController` declared variable. The value given is: `TextEditingController()`, which represents a new instance of a object from this class. *You cannot do this line, without doing the other one first.* Or else the compiler wouldn't know what the name `titleController` represents.

(Also, *it makes sense*, right? First you have a variable of a specific type, and you give this variable a value of that same type.)

So you usually do both. First you declare the variable, then you give it a value. Maybe because all of the keywords are related to "TextEditingController" it confuses a little bit. Here is an equivalent example with the String class:

```
String a; // the first line
a = "Your String"; // the second line
```

Which is equivalent and can be done in a single line as:

```
String a = "Your String";
// Or, in your case:
TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
```

This way you both declare the variable and give it a initial value.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is not initialized and the second example is. For me, there's no scenario where I would declare a `TextEditingController` without initializing it. Although you might be able to pass in a null controller into a `TextFormField` without an error, as soon as you try to do anything with it, like add a listener for example, you will get a "called on null" error.

You might as well just initialize it right off the bat, then it's ready to go immediately.

```
final titleController = TextEditingController();
```